# How to write a lambda expression take in a collection of properties using a delimiter?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am not sure how to create this expression:

```
(e => e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3)
```

I want to pass an expression like this into a method so I can iterate through the collection and pull out the property names.

pseudo method:

```
public  void ParseProperties<T>(The_Expression_being_Passed_In)
{
    foreach(var member in expression.members)
    {
       .....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept a parameter of type

```
params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions
```

So you can say

```
public void ParseProperties<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] expressions) {
    foreach(var expression in expressions) {
        expression.GetPropertyName();
    }
}
```

You'll have to write `GetPropertyName`; implementations abound on StackOverflow.

You can't quite call it like you desire. You'll have to say

```
ParseProperties(e => e.Prop1, e => e.Prop2, e => e.Prop3);
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try something like this, but it may blow up on you if you try to use a value type property as the expression will most likely be a cast expression.

```
public PropertyInfo ParseProperty<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> expr)
{
       MemberExpression member;
       if(expr == null) 
              throw new ArgumentNullException("expr");
       if((member = expr.Body as MemberExpression) == null) 
              throw new ArgumentException("incorrect format");
       return member.Member as PropertyInfo;
}

public PropertyInfo[] ParseProperties<T>(params Expression<Func<T,object>> expressions)
{
      return Array.ConvertAll(expressions,ParseProperty);
}
```

Comment: This implementation is very incomplete. There are already very good implementations of this method on `StackOverflow`.

Comment: It's really not. The only thing missing is the check for ConvertExpressions.